# IE9 border-radius

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

curved css corners for some reason dont seem to work in IE9. I know it supports it however i have looked all over the web for a solution and cant find one that works for me. I tried putting `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` but that did'nt work. I used the .htc file and `behavior: url(border-radius.htc);` however that only works sometimes when switching to compatibility mode. I even tried declairing all 4 values, and didnt make a diffrence. Work beautifuly in firefox, chrome, and safari but not in IE. Any help? Check it out: [my web page](http://aliahealthcare.com/NEWHOME.php) If you have some debugging tool might help you help me.

Comment: your page looks great in my IE9. You probably can't see rounded corner because of that htc file

Comment: so you see rounded corners? and i have the file, should i remove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the page is firing Quirks Mode, try moving those script & css includes down inside the  tag... nothing should ever come between a doctype and it's html tag.

Detail explanation here [Investigating Document Mode Issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ie/gg699340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: changed that and still no result!

Comment: trying correcting the majority of the issues in the w3c validator.  especially any trailing slashes in self closing tags (img, link, etc), they are not valid in HTML4

Answer (score 8):

I found if your using the CSS style `filter` for IE8 and below browsers it will interfere with IE9 styles causing `border-radius` to not work and possible other ill effects.

To fix it add this to your html head:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<style type="text/css">.elementClass { filter: none !important; }</style>
<![endif]-->'
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the vendor extensions, `-moz-border-radius:15px; -ms-border-radius:15px; -o-border-radius:15px; -webkit-border-radius:15px; border-radius:15px;`

You really only need the `-ms` version for what you want, but if you include them all you provide a broader spectrum of coverage.

Comment: tried that and its a no go, you can see it in the source code

Comment: yo, pull the this block   &#60;script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"&#62;&#60;/script&#62; 
&#60;script src="ajax_framework.js" language="javascript"&#62;&#60;/script&#62;
&#60;script src="js/popup.js" type="text/javascript"&#62;&#60;/script&#62; 
&#60;link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyle.css" /&#62;   into your &#60;head&#62; element   i don't think it's your IE

Comment: thats my javascript ? my site needs that?

Comment: the popup.css doesn't have the proprietary extensions http://aliahealthcare.com/js/popup.css

Comment: not 100% sure what u mean by that but thats not my main css, thats just for my popup. My main css is the mystyle.css

Comment: yeah but the popup.css is coming after your main stylesheet and hitting it later in the cascade. looking at your main stylesheet, i only see the vendor declarations on #pic, but even then you're overwriting @ least some of it by redeclaring border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px on the same selector. popup.css has #list defined in it, and i don't see that in your stylesheet, so add #list with the vendor properties + border radius into your stylesheet.

Comment: i honestly cant follow what your saying, can u say that in a simpler way? sorry. You want me to move the #list to the mystyle.css instead of the popup.css?

Comment: you dont have to move it, just add the vendor extensions (-moz-border-radius, etc) to #list declaration.

Answer (score 2):

I found that my border radius in ie9 is working on localhost but not on a server. Im using css3PIE to acomidate ie8 and below, would this be interfering with ie9?

Answer (score 1):

IE9 don't need any prefix for `border-radius` (for sure you don't need `-ms-` prefix at least for this property!). Your browser probably have a problem. Maybe you're running beta or something like that.

Please test this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C59F3/) in another IE9 running computer or have your IE restarted and try it to see IE9 renders `border-radius` just fine.

Comment: that example works just fine! why wont my site work? is there anything tht can conflict with border-radius ?

Comment: did you tried to load IE without add-ons? You can press F12 in IE9 and bring up developer tools. Then click on that little refresh button then inspect your element using that cursor icon. Then go to "Attribute" tab in right pan and add border-radius style. It's kind of like chrome dev tools.

Comment: thats the strange thing ie doesnt even see the border-radius css code?

Comment: I would test it in another computer. :)

Comment: ok so i found the issue, my page loads in quirks mode, not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Quirks mode is where IE9 switches back to IE5 functionality
(added following link to @seanmetzgar post also)

Detail explanation here [Investigating Document Mode Issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ie/gg699340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

With a site I look after, which had ASP code right at the top of page, I added

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

just in front of the  tag, below the code, and IE9 stopped going into Quirks Mode.