# IE9 filter gradient and border-radius conflict

Tags: filter, internet-explorer-9, css

I'm trying to use gradient effect and border radius on same element, but there is a conflict between them. Gradient works fine, but it makes border radius not working.

here is the script

```
.selector {
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff4317',endColorstr='#891a00');
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I don't want to use any `.htc` files.

Is this known issue between filter and border radius?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298929/rounded-corners-not-working-in-ie9

try that

Comment: I would avoid the filter in IE9 and use svg instead.  I usually use this handy tool for generating the css for gradients: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 8):

You can use an SVG gradient, here's an example that works in IE9 with a `border-radius`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Egn9A/

To generate the SVG gradient, use: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/. You don't mention trying to make it work in other browsers/versions of IE, but if that's what you're trying to do (you might be because you're using `filter`), use the method described in the "IE9 Support" section.

Another site to generate SVG gradients: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/svggradientbackgroundmaker/default.html

Answer (score 4):

**Use these classes for border radius and gradient**

**HTML Code:**

**`<div class="box-radius ">border radius with gradient</div>`**

**CSS Code:**

```
.box-radius {
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
           -moz-border-radius: 5px;
             -o-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;  
        /* behavior: url(border-radius.htc); */
    }

.gradient {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff4317, #891a00); /* Firefox 3.6 */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #ff4317),color-stop(1, #891a00)); /* Safari & Chrome */
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#ff4317',endColorstr='#891a00'); /* IE6 & IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#ff4317',endColorstr='#891a00')"; /* IE8 */
```