# My Background Color is spilling outside my 1px border in the form of a box... IE ONLY

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I was playing around one day with background gradients and borders just for fun and I noticed something in IE. 
[image]

The background color is spilling outside the radius border but only in IE. I am using IE 9 and it's not in quirks mode.

Here is the code I am using in my css:

```
body { background-color:#e0dfdf; }

.mainbaloon { background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#7db9e8 100%); overflow: hidden; /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
        background-clip: padding-box;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
        width: 750px;
        border: 1px solid #000;


/* Border Radius for All Browsers START */
        border-radius: .5em;
        -moz-border-radius: .5em;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
        -ms-border-radius:.5em;
/* Border Radius for All Browsers END */
```

So far I have tried the Meta tag thing

> `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

and then the -ms-border-radius thing as well as trying various attempts with

```
overflow:hidden;
background-clip:
```

or whatever that is.

I am mentally exhausted.. lol.. what else could be making this background spill over like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounded corners not working in IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9298929/1211187).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue that affects older versions of Internet Explorer. One simple work-around is to wrap the element in a container that has the same border-radius, and no visible overflow:

```css
.mainbaloonContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: .5em;
}
```

This container will mimic the same roundedness, but hide the overflow. In your case, the element has an explicit width of 750px, so you'll want to make sure the container is the same width. Otherwise, the container wouldn't be narrow enough to obscure the right-edges of your inner element.