# Simple CSS making trouble with IE 9

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS code:

```css
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande', Arial, Sans-Serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #555;
}

#wrapper {
    width:950px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
       -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
}
```

In Chrome it works perfectly, the wrapper is in the middle of any screen resolution and has curve border.

But very big trouble when it comes to IE9, the wrapper sticks to the left, the border doesn't show and other stuff.

Comment: That's a problem with IE 9 .. It isn't webkit or Mozilla and can't handle complex borders properly or 3d or a bunch of things

Comment: you should remove position:relative; It doesn't make any sense there.

Comment: removing position:relative doesn't work.

At least making the wrapper gets into the middle of the browser for IE9 can't be work out?

Comment: If the wrapper is a DIV, you want `margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto` to align it in the center. I guess it works for all. Also, the border radius thing won't work in IE, because it doesn't support CSS3 borders like that.

Comment: margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto <--- still doesn't work bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post regarding rounded corners and IE 9 - [IE9 border-radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369796/ie9-border-radius)

PS - Went to go troubleshoot this in IE9 on my VM and jsfiddle doesn't work in IE9 lol.

Answer (score 0):

Think you need this

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

paste it between the `<head></head>` tags

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify a correct doctype? This is just guesswork since you didn't share any HTML code.