# How to make buttons with rounded corner in IE 9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

```
.button_style
{
    color:#FFF;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: #2faa51;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2faa51 0%, #207337 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #2faa51), color-stop(100%, #207337));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2faa51 0%, #207337 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2faa51 0%, #207337 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2faa51 0%, #207337 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2faa51 0%, #207337 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2faa51', endColorstr='#207337', GradientType=0 );
    border:1px solid #178636;
    padding:0px 5px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:13px !important;
    line-height:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
    behavior: url(images/ie-css3.htc); 
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;

}
```

Tried ie-css3 and the above CSS, but can find only round corners carved(outlined) but not rounded edges.Edges are still pointed corners.How to make it a rounded corner button from all four sides.Please help me for this.

Comment: border-radius is supported OOTB on IE9 (and in all other browsers to) Without vendor prefix (so remove all these `-webkit-border-*-radius` ;)

Comment: @ByScripts: But early versions of Chrome and Safari use the prefixed property. Also, Firefox uses different values than the standards.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7369888/1577396)

Comment: @TomSarduy Chrome and Safari stopped to use prefix since v5.0 (pretty old, almost no longer used). And what you mean by " Firefox uses different values than the standards"? Never heard of this.

Comment: @ByScripts: You're right, I was confused. Firefox use different values for others properties like `gradient`

Answer (score 1):

No prefix needed for IE:

```
border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
```

With IE9, the important steps are using the edge META tag (in the header):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

> "edge" means "use the latest rendering engine" so IE 9 will use 9, 10 uses 10, etc.

and provide the behavior hack:

```
behavior: url(images/ie-css3.htc);
```